# Two definitions - do they differ?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following definitions which may be true or false but for me it seems like both true

A) If ($a_{2n} - a_n$) converges to $0$ then $a_n$ converges.
B) If $a_n$ converges then ($a_{2n} - a_n$) converges to $0$

I don't feel like both can be true at the same time but I couldn't find why

Comment: Note that the expression in brackets is a subset of the initial sequence and thus there could be other terms that don't follow this rule while the second statement is a bit stronger than the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any natural number $n$ can be written uniquely in the form $2^k\cdot t$ where $k$ is a nonnegative integer and $t$ is an odd positive integer.  In this notation, we will call $t$ the 'odd part' of $n$.  If we define a sequence by $a_n$ is equal to the odd part of $n$, then this sequence gives a counterexample to (A).

I think (B) is true.

Comment: Is it "legit" to define a sequence like that? do you have a numeric example for this sequence?

Comment: @kfir124: It is 'legit'--there is a well-defined rule of formation for the sequence.  The sequence goes: $1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 5,\dots$

Comment: So $a_{2n}$ should be $1,1,3,1,5...$ which actually equals to $a_n$ oh cool I could never think about such a sequence

Comment: Yes.  In fact if you let $b_n=a_{2n}$, then $b_n=a_n$ for all $n$.